# erratic behaviour sending bytes via bluetooth on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have managed to get Bluetooth working writing to a PIC from Android.
I have had my code sending a 0 and a 1 to turn an LED on and off, and getting the PIC to send a response.
I am now trying to send two bytes at a time to control multiple LED's.
The PIC changes the state of the LED depending on the control byte sent.
I have had this working using RealTerm to test the PIC and it works fine.
When I send the bytes from the App, the PIC receives them correctly sometimes and not others.

I've created an array of bytes for each message.

```
byte[] Led1On = {(byte)245,(byte)1}; // LED 1 on
byte[] Led1Off = {(byte)245,(byte)0}; // LED 1 off
byte[] Led2On = {(byte)244,(byte)1}; // LED 2 on
byte[] Led2Off = {(byte)244,(byte)0}; // LED 2 off
```

and send them from the Switch onClick.

```
public void switch1Clicked(View v){
    // check that we have connected bluetooth first
    if(!ConStatus) {
        // if not don't action switch
        Log.d(TAG, "switch 1 clicked when not connected");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Connected Yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ((Switch) v).setChecked(false);
    }else {
        boolean state = ((Switch) v).isChecked();

        if (state) {
            mConnectedThread.write(Led1On);    // Send "245" then "1" via Bluetooth
        } else {
            mConnectedThread.write(Led1Off);    // Send "245" then "1" via Bluetooth
        }
    }
}
```

using a write function

```
    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] message) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "...Data to send: " + Integer.toString(message) + "...");
        //byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "...Error data send: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
        }
    }
```

I'm quite new to Android and Java but have managed to get this code working to a point using this site and others for samples.